# Writing an assembler for Lattice GAL devices

Tags: programmable-logic, assembler

I am writing a compiler for the Lattice GAL10V8 and GAL16V8 PLDs. (And, yes I know that these chips are now obsolete.)

I have completed the compiler as far as parsing the logic equations and pin assignments/mappings goes, but I can't find any documentation on the Lattice website, or elsewhere on the Internet on the format of the fuse map for these devices to enable me to generate the JEDEC file for input to a programmer. Is this proprietary information and am I faced with having to reverse engineer the JEDEC files created by a tool such as WinCUPL? Any pointers to useful documentation and/or source code would be appreciated.

Comment: This will help ... http://matthieu.benoit.free.fr/ST_GAL_devices_programmer.htm. I have transmitted the original programs (LogicLab 2000 now obsolete) of this programmer. It writes also JEDEC files. Good luck !

Comment: this will help too ... https://usermanual.wiki/Document/1991LatticeGALDataBook.1566316052/view

Comment: There is also this (ancient) project: [https://github.com/daveho/GALasm](https://github.com/daveho/GALasm)